# Winform C# Application, how do I align text inside a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I would like to create a button with a plus sign, however when I created the plus sign with the text, it is not aligned from the top of the button as in the image below:

[image]

The problem occurs when I try to increase the font size. In default size of the text the plus sign is centered. What can I do to center it in my case?

TextAlign (TopLeft) and UseCompatibleTextRendering didn't work. (Winforms C# Visual Studio 2019)

**Note**: Text align property did not work because my font size is larger than default it is 36+.

Comment: Could you please tell me what can do to improve the question?

Comment: In Visual Studio, in the Properties pane, there should be an ImageAlign property on the `Button` control. It exists for VB.NET WinForms, so I assume it also exists for C# WinForms.

Comment: @HardCode I am not aligning a image man, I am aligning a text.

Comment: So then the `TextAlign` property?

Comment: @HardCode Read My Question, I tried textAlign It doesnt Work. Did you suggest question to be closed, with this reason?

Comment: Which font and font size are you using? `button.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;` works well for me with Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt

Comment: @KaiThoma It might be becuase I used "topLeft" I will try MiddleCenter this evening, and update you.

Comment: @KaiThoma Text align didn't work because of my font size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an png of **+** from resource instead of setting directly the text property of the button.

**Example**

```
this.button1.Image = NameSpace1.Properties.Resources.Image2.png;
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I couldn't find a  "+" sign Png with transparent background :). Also my button is 30x30 size

Comment: give ma a second I'll make a one for u with high ppi to avoid bluring

Comment: How do you make it? Could you teach me? I also need 1 more button image.

Comment: using photoshop or any photo editing app

Comment: Thank you Ahmed Alayat. I upvoted your answer, let me wait litle bit more if no one can find a solution, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Images are not the same resolution on all pcs, it might look really clean on your pc but if someone else runs the application it might be way lower res

Comment: the "+" https://ibb.co/gWvJKnH

Comment: Th image in this link https://ibb.co/gWvJKnH is 9000 pixel per inch I think there is no screen that beat this number up till now. also you can use whatever font u want to make the pic

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set the Button's `FlatStyle` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatstyle?view=net-5.0) to `System` (`System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System`), if you are Ok to change the `FlatStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

I created a test application and the combination of font "Microsoft Sans Serif" in size 36pt with button size 32x32px and `FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System` (as elimad already mentioned) works quite well for me.

[image: Screenshot of code below]

```
namespace ControlTest
{
    public class MainForm : Form
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }

        private Button button1;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System;
            this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 36F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 16);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 32);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "+";
            // 
            // MainForm
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(157, 92);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "MainForm";
            this.Text = "ControlTest";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create custom controls and then render the text yourself

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f5a10c/creating-custom-controls-in-C-Sharp/

After compiling it should just show up inside the toolbox